# How do you discover model attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am finding it difficult to easily see what attributes/properties exist on all of my model classes since they are not explicitly defined in my class files.

To discover model attributes, I keep the schema.rb file open and flip between it and whatever code I'm writing as needed.  This works but is clunky because I have to switch between reading the schema file to pick up attributes, the model class file to check methods, and whatever new code that I'm writing to call attributes & methods.

My question is, how do you discover model attributes when you're analyzing a Rails codebase for the first time?  Do you keep the schema.rb file open all the time, or is there a better way that doesn't involve jumping between schema file & model file constantly?

Comment: Thanks for the answers below.  It sounds like there's not a good way to declare attribute names in the model source file, but rather keep a terminal open and poke the objects to find out their properties.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

For Schema related stuff

```
Model.column_names         
Model.columns_hash         
Model.columns
```

For instance variables/attributes in an AR object

```
object.attribute_names                    
object.attribute_present?          
object.attributes
```

For instance methods without inheritance from super class

```
Model.instance_methods(false)
```

Comment: To get the associations too you can do: Model.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)

Comment: In ActiveRecord 5 (and probably earlier) you can call `Model.attribute_names`.

Answer (score 30):

There is a rails plugin called Annotate models, that will generate your model attributes on the top of your model files
here is the link:

https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models

to keep the annotation in sync, you can write a task to re-generate annotate models after each deploy.

Comment: New site for what I assume is the same plugin, https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models

Answer (score 21):

If you're just interested in the properties and data types from the database, you can use `Model.inspect`.

```
irb(main):001:0> User.inspect
=> "User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string,
 reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime,
 remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer,
 current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime,
 current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime,
 updated_at: datetime)"
```

Alternatively, having run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` for your development environment, the file `db/schema.rb` will contain the authoritative source for your database structure:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130712162401) do
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

To describe model I use following snippet

```
Model.columns.collect { |c| "#{c.name} (#{c.type})" }
```

Again this is if you are looking pretty print to describe you `ActiveRecord` without you going trough migrations or hopping that developer before you was nice enough to comment in attributes.

Comment: This is perfect for printing out all the attributes of all the instances for a particular model - thanks!

Answer (score 9):

```
some_instance.attributes
```

Source: [blog](http://blog.codefront.net/2008/02/13/living-on-the-edge-of-rails-7-improved-activerecordbaseattributes-time-zone-support/)

Comment: some_class.attributes.keys is a little cleaner

Comment: wonder if any IDEs use this for autocompletion? Seems like an obvious thing to do for a rails model. I'm always disappointed when I start typing an attribute name and it doesn't autocomplete.

Comment: @frankodwyer - RubyMine does, although I"m sure there must be others.