# How can you discover accessible attribute names from a model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291395/414825) says you can do `object.attribute_names` to get a list of attribute names for a model instance.

But is there any way to get a list of all its *accessible* attribute names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`accessible_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/accessible_attributes)**.

You have to provide a role, because different roles can have different accessible attributes.

If you want to have the attributes from a model instance you can use this code:

```
@my_model.class.accessible_attributes(:admin) # Returns array of symbols
```