# Rails3 - How do I get all attributes and associations of an ActiveRecord Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes, associations

I was looking for a method to get an array of all model attributes and associations on an ActiveRecord model. I had a hard time finding the answer to this question, so, I will post my answer and see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all attributes

```
m = Model.new
m.attributes
```

To get all Model associations

```
Model.reflect_on_all_associations.map{|x| x.class_name}.compact
```

These links will provide more details
[How do you discover model attributes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289557/how-do-you-discover-model-attributes-in-rails)

http://www.funonrails.com/2009/11/how-to-get-all-associted-models-of.html

Comment: Note that reflect_on_all_associations.map{|x| x.class_name} get the *class name* of the association, not the association name itself.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is:

```
m = Model.find(id)
m.attributes.keys.concat(m.reflections.map{|r| r.first.to_s})
```