# Rails 3 + Rspec: Testing that a model has an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a way to test that a model has a specific attribute? Right now I am just using `respond_to` like this:

```
describe Category do
  it { should respond_to(:title) }
  ...
end
```

to test that the Category model has an attribute, but that only really tests that there is an instance method called `title`. However, I can see how in some situations they would behave synonymously.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can test for the presence of an attribute in an instance of the model with the following:

```
it "should include the :title attribute" do
  expect(subject.attributes).to include(:title)
end
```

or using the `its` method (in a separate gem as of RSpec 3.0):

```
its(:attributes) { should include("title") }
```

See the related [How do you discover model attributes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289557/how-do-you-discover-model-attributes-in-rails). (Nod to @Edmund for correcting the `its` example.)

Comment: @Edmund You have no idea how embarrassed/thankful I am for you pointing out that error. I left the argument as a symbol since it can accept that _or_ a string.

Comment: No problem. It wasn't working with a symbol for me though. It had to be a string. I think it's because it's just a ruby hash, not a rails `HashWithIndifferentAccess`

Comment: No, you were right on that, too. I was confusing the ability of `its` to take a symbol instead of a string as a parameter. Yikes! Corrected.

Comment: Doesn't this return `true` even if the value is nil?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a necropost, but I wrote a custom rspec matcher that should make testing the presence of a model attribute easier:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_attribute do |attribute|
  chain :with_value do |value|
    @value = value
  end

  match do |model|
    r = model.attributes.include? attribute.to_s
    r &&= model.attributes[attribute] == @value if @value
    r
  end

  failure_message do |model|
    msg = "Expected #{model.inspect} to have attribute #{attribute}"
    msg += " with value #{@value}" if @value
    msg
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |model|
    msg = "Expected #{model.inspect} to not have attribute #{attribute}"
    msg += " with value #{@value}" if @value
    msg
  end
end
```

Comment: The [`have_attributes` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/have-attributes-matcher) now exists since [RSpec 3.1](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/09/rspec-3-1-has-been-released/#expectations-new-haveattributes-matcher).

Answer (score 0):

You could test for the class, if that's what you mean:

```
@category.title.class.should eq String
```

or you could define a test instance and then test against that.

```
@category = FactoryGirl.build(:category)
@category.title.should eq <title from factory>
```