# generate data from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

Let's say I have `User(name, password, email, zip code)` table and I want to generate User objects with random data.

Is there a command( to use on rails console), which does that? something like User.generate.

Comment: Do you want generate fake data to seed your data base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the Faker gem to your gemfile, add this to your user.rb file.

```
def self.generate_new
  name     = Faker::Name.name 
  password = "foobar"
  email    = Faker::Internet.email
  zip      = Faker::Address.zip 
  User.create!(name:     name,
               passowrd: password,
               email:    email,
               zip:      zip)
end
```

After restarting your console, the command `User.generate_new` should run this command and generate a new user with random inputs.

Comment: Is there a way to know in advance what are compulsory fields that need to be filled in before creating an object(I don't want to check the presence validations each time I want to create an object)

Comment: Do you want to skip the validations? Or are you just trying to find all the fields associated with the user and have it fill in data automatically?

Comment: I am trying to find all the fields associated with the user and have it fill in data automatically

Comment: @OmarLahlou I don't think that's possible. You can get column names [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1291395/3251199) but getting variable types and such is not quite feasible, at least to my knowledge. You'll just have to add to this function whenever you add a new attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this gem: https://github.com/stympy/faker

It creates fake data for objects.