# How can you see what attributes a certain Model has in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just realized that aside from checking the database or reading all the migrations that contributed to a certain model, I'm not really sure how I would find out what attributes a certain Model had in a Rails project. In any other context I've ever worked in, I would go look at the file where the Model definition was (the class file, per se) to find out something like that.

How is this normally done in Rails when you join a pre-existing project and are learning the code? Just by using the Rails console?

Comment: `db/schema.rb` shows your database tables. For your second question I guess this is the same with all MVC frameworks: reading models and controllers and maybe some help from a team member for big apps with tens of models

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about it! Very new to rails, sorry for the beginner question. Thank you.

Comment: It is still useful to have PGadmin open. Also even if I work with Sublime IDE, Rubymine has a tab that shows all database tables with their content. pretty useful

Comment: you can read this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289557/how-do-you-discover-model-attributes-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use "[Annotate](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models)", this gem automatically add a structured comment in you model(fixtures, factories...) when you make a migration, like this:

```
# == Schema Info
#
# Table name: line_items
#
#  id                  :integer(11)    not null, primary key
#  quantity            :integer(11)    not null
#  product_id          :integer(11)    not null
#  unit_price          :float
#  order_id            :integer(11)
#

 class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
```

Remember to add this gem in the development group:

```
group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
end
```

and run this command `rails g annotate:install` to create a rake task. The rake task will be called at every migration

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Secondary question though, I'm not familiar with the console syntax you're using there. I thought you had to run something like `rails g task` and then fill out the file by hand. Where can I see documentation on the way you're doing it there, which I don't really understand?

Comment: `rails g annotate:install` will run their custom install file. You can get more info here: https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/blob/develop/README.rdoc#configuration-in-rails